# @requestmapping precendence order query for Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to understand the order in which @RequestMapping in Spring MVC works. I have two different controllers as follows

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody RequestResponse test() {
        log.info("test processed");
        ....
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody RequestResponse userTest() {
        log.info("user test processed");
        ....
    }
}
```

When I make a request www.test.com/user/test, I was expecting UserController.userTest() method to be called, but what I see is that TestController.test() method is being called.

Here's the logging turned on for Spring

```
DEBUG; tid:http-bio-8080-exec-8; DispatcherServlet; DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/test-web/user/test]
DEBUG; tid:http-bio-8080-exec-8; AbstractHandlerMethodMapping; Looking up handler method for path /test
DEBUG; tid:http-bio-8080-exec-8; AbstractHandlerMethodMapping; Returning handler method [public com.test.dto.RequestResponse com.test.controller.TestController.test()]
DEBUG; tid:http-bio-8080-exec-8; AbstractBeanFactory; Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'testController'
```

Can someone clarify on the order of Type and Method level @RequestMapping order or any documentation about this?

Debugged some more and based on the debugging I can deduce that the way it seems to be working (and this is by no means an answer to my question) is that `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping` in Spring evaluates the requests from right to left.

For an incoming request `/user/test`, `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping` would first lookup any handler method for `/test`, if found (which in my case it does) it would pass the request to that method - `TestController.test()`, in this case. If it doesn't find any mapped handler methods then it would look for any handler method for /user/test.

I find that a bit bizzare, but this is what I have observed in the logs. Can anyone substantiate this with some official documentation?

Comment: Judging from what is happening and the logging your servlet is mapped to `/user`. The mapping is calculated for the url inside the `DispatcherServlet`. So in this case `/test`.

Answer (score 0):

First class-level `RequestMapping` is checked and then the method-level one. So the behavior you're telling is not possible afaik.

Comment: I have added some debug log from Spring and I spent couple of hours after I figured out this was the behaviour that was happening. I just want to understand it and rectify it.